# Exfat-fuse error while copying files

Tags: usb, mount, unmount, exfat, fuse

Installed exfat-fuse and exfat-utils from Ubuntu repositories. First, everything was ok, USB HDD 1 TB worked perfectly, automounted and write and read was ok. But then I tried to move my Movies folder to USB HDD. It started moving and suddenly error appeared: "Cannot move file to "mount point name" because of input/output error. 
It promted to skip this file but it was the same for all of them. Then it said that my device is not mounted properly and denied access to it though it showed it in Nautilus. Ubuntu showed window with promt to send error message, inside there was an information telling that exfat-fuse had unexpected error and closed. 
And when I remounted device after reinstalling software I tried the same task. As expected, there was empty folder on my hdd and system asked me to replace it, I clicked ok and it suddenly closed with the same error.
I tried to not move files but copy them into another folder and it was ok. So the problem appeared only when I tried to move (not copy) files or folders to USB HDD, delete them from USB HDD, or replace files or folders with same existing ones from my Netbook.
I cannot put log file here cause I can't find information about exact problems with mounting my device in sys logs.
Any help is welcome

Comment: Now it allows me to copy and delete all files I want except two empty folders that I tried to copy to hdd and it showed me input output error. Now I cannot delete them and cannot copy or move files into them